# Accessing values in list inside dictionary when you don't know the count

Tags: python

I have output in below form:

```
data = {ItemA: [123456, 123654], ItemB: [456789, 456987]}
```

To get the values, I can access them as data.ItemA[0], data.ItemA[1]

But how do you deal when you don't know how many values are there for ItemA in the list. How can I get all individual values of ItemA without knowing how many items will be in list beforehand.

Comment: With a `for` loop, just like processing any other list when you don't know its length.

Comment: Python doesn't use `data.ItemA` to access a dict, it's `data['ItemA']`.

Answer (score 3):

You can just access the entire list and use it however you want:

```
data = {'ItemA': [123456, 123654], 'ItemB': [456789, 456987]}
my_list = data['ItemA']
```

`my_list` will then just be the entire list, and you can check its length, pull out specific items (like you were doing before), iterate through it etc.

Answer (score 3):

So for that you need to iterate over dictionary and than from the key you get you need to iterate the list inside that.

```
data = {'ItemA': [123456, 123654], 'ItemB': [456789, 456987]}
for key in data:
    for items in data[key]:
        print(key ,':' , items)
```

Key will iterate over dictionary and contains 'ItemA' and 'ItemB'. Then from there yoū can iterate over that dictionary key and get list

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {ItemA: [123456, 123654], ItemB: [456789, 456987]}

for value in data['ItemA']
    print value

output:
123456
123654
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the count per key, you can do something like below

```
data = {'ItemA': [123456, 123654], 'ItemB': [456789, 456987]}

for i in data.keys():
    print("Key:", i, "\tData:" ,data[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to retrieve list of item from dictionary value

```
data = {"ItemA": [123456, 123654], "ItemB": [456789, 456987]}

for item in data['ItemA']:
    print item
```

output:

```
123456
123654
```